# Angular dynamic module provider

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, module

I have a module which should have injected a service depending on the router path, e.g.
for a path with `/demo` it should have injected a `DemoService` and for paths without `/demo` it should have provided a `UserService`.

How can I implement such functionality?

Of course I could inject both services and in the module itself determine whether it should use a `DemoService` or a `UserService` but then the module wouldn't be reusable in other apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Define a type for a provider, let's say, in your case you can have a class provider, like a factory class, e.g.

```
abstract class DataService {
  abstract doSomething(): void;
}

class FactoryService {
  activeService = new BehaviorSubject<DataService>();

  getService(): Observable<DataService> {
    return this.activeService.asObservable();
  }
}

class DemoService extends DataService {
  doSomething(): void {
    console.log('DemoService');
  }
}
class UserService extends DataService {
  doSomething(): void {
    console.log('UserService');
  }
}
```

take the shared parts of an API of your services to an abstract class, so the consumers should rely on the interface.

2. In your module which should provide either `DemoService` or `UserService` define your provider as a factory e.g.

```
providers: [{
  provide: FactoryService,
  useFactory: (route: ActivatedRoute) => {
    const factoryService = new FactoryService();
    const url = route['_routerState'].snapshot.url;

    url.startsWith('/demo/')
      ? factoryService.activeService.next(new DemoService())
      : factoryService.activeService.next(new UserService());

    return factoryService;
  }
  deps: [ActivatedRoute]
}],
```

3. In your consumer component, you now can get access to the particular service through `ServiceFactory` which should provide a proper service

```
constructor(private factoryService: FactoryService) {
  this.factoryService.activeService.subscribe((activeService: DataService) => {
    // Here you can now do stuff with an proper service
  });
}
```

Hope, you've got the idea...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, that's not what I've meant. I was trying to avoid any kind of logic about which service a module should use in a module itself. Imagine that you'd want to serve it as npm (which I wouldn't, but I'd like to do this this way). The module only needs to get data and pass data, it shouldn't determine which service to use. Or am I thinking wrong about this whole thing?

Comment: In the example that I provided, you can place the logic of defining a service regarding `localtion.path` in a root module or any other module that should be up in a hierarchy of your module, that should consume the actual `DemoService` or `UserService`. So the module-consumer will be devoid of knowledge about the final service that it will be using and will be using the service which will be provided by the parent module. The thing is, that anyway the logic of defining a final service should exist somewhere...

Comment: Another way which might work is to 1. put your `path-service` right configuration inside `environment.ts` like so `service: { locationPath: 'demo', servicePath: './demo.service.ts' } 2. define `ngDoBootstrap` method for `AppModule`, ` and grab the service path from `environment.ts` 3. dynamically import class with `import(environment.service[servicePath)` 4. Create injector and add the loaded class. 5. Attach the injector to the AppComponent in `ngDoBootstrap` method. Personally, I haven't tried this on my own, but in theory, it should work...

Comment: I've been trying to implement your first solution but I think there's a problem with `this.serviceFactory.activeService.subscribe()` in a component constructor, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` error. I also tried with getService() but no luck here either, what is this method for?

Comment: Oops, my bad... You're receiving a `TypeError` due to `activeService` was a static property. I updated the code and now it should work, basically, I defined `activeService` property and `getService()` method as a public, not static... So if you change those in your code, this line `this.serviceFactory.activeService.subscribe()` will work.

Comment: thanks, now I got a little bit further. However, when I subscribe to the service (your 3rd piece of code) and call a method from my UserService I get an error in IDE `Property 'getBoard()' does not exist on type 'ServiceFactory' and I get an `undefined` as response. Of course I've added `extends ServiceFactory` to the `UserService`

Comment: I updated a little the 1. point of my answer, actually, there is no necessity to make `UserService` or `DemoService` as heirs of `ServiceFactory`. I've added an abstract class `DataService` which should contain an interface which is implemented by `DemoService` or `UsersService`, so for the sake of this example let it be `doSomething()` method. I assume, that `UserService` or `DemoService` should have exactly the same interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189777/discussion-between-dandy-and-nakhodkiin).

Comment: I've managed to make the above code work. What I needed to change was using `BehaviorSubject()` instead of `Subject()` and, what also took me a lot of time, the logic in the module to determine which service to use was also not correct, I was getting `undefined` all the time. what I used was: 
`const factoryService = new FactoryService(); const url = route['_routerState'].snapshot.url; url.startsWith('/demo/') ? factoryService.activeService.next(new DemoService()) : factoryService.activeService.next(new UserService()); return factoryService;`
Please update and I'll mark your answer